# Code not picking up two sections

Tags: c++, file-io

I have this code to average out scores from a file.
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("Quizzes.dat");
ofstream fout("readout2.dat");


int main(void)
{
  fout.setf(ios::showpoint);
  fout.setf(ios::fixed);
  fout.precision(2);
  int id, newid, count = 0;
  float score, maxscore, minscore, scoretotal = 0, testavg;
  fin >> id >> score;

  while (!fin.fail()) {
    maxscore = 0;
    minscore = 100;
    scoretotal = 0;
    count = 0;
    testavg = 0;
    newid = id;

    while (id == newid && !fin.fail()) {
      if (score <= minscore && score >= maxscore) {
        minscore = score;
        maxscore = score;
      }//end of if(score < minscore && score > maxscore)

      else if (minscore == maxscore && score == minscore) {
        scoretotal = scoretotal + score;
        count++;

      } else if (score <= minscore && minscore == maxscore) {
        minscore = score;
      }//end of else if(score < minscore && minscore == maxscore)

      else if (score >= maxscore && minscore == maxscore) {
        maxscore = score;
      }//End of else if(score > maxscore && minscore == maxscore)

      else if (score <= minscore) {
        scoretotal = minscore + scoretotal;
        count++;
        minscore = score;
      }//end of else if(score < minscore)

      else if (score >= maxscore) {
        scoretotal = maxscore + scoretotal;
        count++;
        maxscore = score;
      }//End of else if (score > maxscore)

      else {
        scoretotal = scoretotal + score;
        count++;
      }

      fin >> id >> score;
    }//end of while(id==newid)

    testavg = (scoretotal / count);
    fout << newid << setw(20) << testavg << endl;
  }//end of while(!fin.fail())
}
```

Here is the file:

```
10234     67

10234    100

10234     53

10234     91

11245     89

11245     46

11245     99

14652    100

14652     56

14652     99

14652    100

14652     96

14652     78

19832     92

19832     78

19832     51

19832     76

19832     89

20014    100

20014    100

20014    100

20014    100

21140     43

21140     56

21140     90

21140     78

21140     63

21140     67

21140     89

22256     10

22256      7

22256      7

22256      2

22256     11

22256      2

22256      2

22256     13

22256      9

27654     83

27654     83

27654     83

27654     83

30021     78

30021     67

30021     92

30021     59

30021     82

30021     58
```

The problem I'm having is on the sections of the file where the score stays the same through out an id it doesn't add anything.

Comment: Prepare a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/) and post it (if you don't spot the bug yourself in the process).

Answer (score 1):

Try to simplify things, your program is very hard to read

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;

  for (int id, score; std::cin >> id >> score;)
    map[id].push_back(score);

  for (auto const& id : map) {
    int total = std::accumulate(id.second.begin(), id.second.end(), 0); 
    std::cout << id.first << ": " 
      << total / static_cast<double>(id.second.size()) << '\n';
  }
}
```

You can also use algorithms like `min_element` and `max_element` if you need to find min and max scores.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some diagnostics so you can trace the logic flow and find the problem. It looks to me like your 7-stage if {} else {} structure is overly complicated and logically incorrect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.txt");
ostream& fout = cout;




int main (void)
{

fout.setf(ios::showpoint);
fout.setf(ios::fixed);
fout.precision (2); 
int id, newid, count=0;
float score, maxscore, minscore, scoretotal=0, testavg;


fin >> id >> score;

while(!fin.fail())
{
    maxscore = 0;
    minscore = 100;
    scoretotal = 0;
    count=0;
    testavg=0;
    newid=id;
    while(id==newid && !fin.fail())
    {
        if(score <= minscore && score >= maxscore)
        {
            cout << "1" << endl;
            minscore = score;
            maxscore = score;
        }//end of if(score < minscore && score > maxscore)
        else if (minscore == maxscore && score == minscore)
        {
            cout << "2" << endl;
            scoretotal = scoretotal + score;
            count++;
        }
        else if(score <= minscore && minscore == maxscore)
        {
            cout << "3" << endl;
            minscore = score;
        }//end of else if(score < minscore && minscore == maxscore)
        else if(score >= maxscore && minscore == maxscore)
        {
            cout << "4" << endl;
            maxscore = score;
        }//End of else if(score > maxscore && minscore == maxscore)

        else if(score <= minscore)
        {
            cout << "5" << endl;
            scoretotal = minscore + scoretotal;
            count++;
            minscore = score;
        }//end of else if(score < minscore)
        else if (score >= maxscore)
        {
            cout << "6" << endl;
            scoretotal = maxscore + scoretotal;
            count++;
            maxscore=score;
        }//End of else if (score > maxscore) 
        else 
        {
            cout << "7" << endl;
            scoretotal = scoretotal + score;
            count++; 
        }
        fin >> id >> score;
    }//end of while(id==newid)
    testavg = (scoretotal/count);
    fout << newid << setw(20) << testavg << endl;
}//end of while(!fin.fail())


}//End of int main(void)
```